# Using $CI_JOB_TOKEN Gives 404 Error On Triggering Pipelines

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to trigger a pipeline using $CI_JOB_TOKEN. But it gives a 404 error everytime. Is there somebody could block CI_JOB_TOKEN from triggering a pipeline ?? at access levels ??

curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master https://gitlab.eample.com/api/v4/projects/73237/trigger/pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me using the CI_JOB_TOKEN also returned a 404 error for a private repository. When I instead executed the same command using a **pipeline trigger token** (`Settings > CI/CD/ Pipeline triggers`) it works as expected.

A similar problem is described in this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17511

Just for clarification: You have to generate the token in the other project and then set it as a custom ci variable e.g. `PIPELINE_TRIGGER_TOKEN` in the project where you want to use it. Then in the curl request within `.gitlab-ci.yml` replace `CI_JOB_TOKEN` with `PIPELINE_TRIGGER_TOKEN`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure the `ref=master` is correct? Recently `master` was changed to `main` your API call might be hitting a non-existent branch hence 404

Answer (score -1):

Check also your GitLab version:

With [GitLab 14.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/07/22/gitlab-14-1-released/#default-branch-name-redirect) (July 2021), you have:

> ### Default branch name redirect
>
> Default branch name redirect
>
> As part of the larger effort to rename Git’s default initial branch in a GitLab project from `master` to `main`, we are adding an automatic redirect to streamline the transition. Previously, when projects renamed the default branch, current URLs would result in `404 Not Found`. This is a frustrating experience when you are trying to navigate between branches. Now, if you navigate to a file or directory path whose default branch was renamed, you will be redirected to the updated path automatically.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/default.html#default-branch-rename-redirect) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/329100).

So your problem might not exist with 14.1.